# JS array index number into value with string replace

Tags: javascript

I have a multidimentional array:

```
(3) [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]
0:["('idDocDetail','0','$createdBy')"]
1:["('idDocDetail','2','$createdBy'),('idDocDetail','4','$createdBy')"]
2:["('idDocDetail','0','$createdBy')"]
```

I need to replace the string value **idDocDetail** with the index number, like this.

```
(3) [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]
0:["('0','0','$createdBy')"]
1:["('1','2','$createdBy'),('1','4','$createdBy')"]
2:["('2','0','$createdBy')"]
```

I'm trying to use replace, but I got the replace is not a function error.

```
array.forEach(function(item, index) {
  return item.toString().replace('idDocDetail', index);
    });
```

what am I doing wrong? Replace is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do recommend you to learn to perform changes in immutable manner. This is where `Array.prototype.map` plays well

```js
const data = [
  ["('idDocDetail','0','$createdBy')"],
  ["('idDocDetail','2','$createdBy'),('idDocDetail','4','$createdBy')"],
  ["('idDocDetail','0','$createdBy')"]
]

const modified = data.map((item, index) => 
   item.map(str => str.replace(/idDocDetail/g, index ))
)

modified.forEach(x => console.log(JSON.stringify(x)))
```

Comment: Thanks man, I use prototype.map to extract info from a table to that array, but I get stuck with the index replace. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Here, this works for your code structure. It uses `map()` to produce a new array by just replacing the string of interest with the index.

EDIT: Added a nested map for clarity + regular expression to find **all** instances of 'idDocDetail' in the string, not just the first one. `replace` method when given a raw `string` value only handles the first instance of a string occurring.

```js
const array = [["('idDocDetail','0','$createdBy')"],
["('idDocDetail','2','$createdBy'),('idDocDetail','4','$createdBy')"],
["('idDocDetail','0','$createdBy')"]]

var find = 'idDocDetail';
var re = new RegExp(find, 'g');

let newArray = array.map((val, i) => val.map(string => {
  return string.replace(re, i)
}))

console.log(newArray)
```

Comment: You're loosing the embedded arrays

Comment: the second row still have the string I want to replace with the index

Comment: Code should be all set now

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over your array and edit it.

```js
let array = [
  ["('idDocDetail','0','$createdBy')"],
  ["('idDocDetail','2','$createdBy'),('idDocDetail','4','$createdBy')"],
  ["('idDocDetail','0','$createdBy')"],
];

array.forEach((e, i) => {
  array[i] = [e[0].replace(/idDocDetail/g, i)];
});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: the second row still have the string I want to replace with the index

Answer (score 0):

`forEach` ignores the return of the callback. You need to assign to the original array at the current index.

```js
var array = [
  ["('idDocDetail','0','$createdBy')"],
  ["('idDocDetail','2','$createdBy'),('idDocDetail','4','$createdBy')"],
  ["('idDocDetail','0','$createdBy')"]
];

array.forEach(function(item, index) {
  array[index] = item.map(s => s.replace('idDocDetail', index));
});

console.log(array);
```

Comment: the second row still have the string 'idDocDetail'

Answer (score 0):

You can not replace an item by calling a method on the item being replaced. Instead you need to call it on the array. You can do it this way:

```
for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    array[i][0] = i;
}
```